# Mapping a Specification over one entity to a query over another

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have two entities, one named Organization, another User. A User belongs to an Organization.

I have a this specification

```
Specification<Organization> isValid = ...
```

and I would like to look up a user by some criteria, including the company being valid. Is there an obvious way to turn a Specification<Organization> into a Specification<User>?

Something like

```
<X, Y> Specification<X> on(SingularAttribute<X, Y> attr, JoinType joinType, Specification<Y> spec) {
  return (root, query, builder) -> {
    final Join<X, Y> join = root.join(attr, joinType));
    return spec.toPredicate(join, query, builder);
  }
}
```

except of course this doesn't work, as toPredicate takes a Root<T>, not a From<?, T>.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's more or less the route I took, but was hoping there was something out  there needing a bit less scaffolding. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to entities Movie, Actor, Producers. Movie had multiple actors and one producers. To perform a search I used this:

```java
private Specification<Movie> searchSpecification(String keyword) {
        return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
            if ((keyword ==null)) {
                return null;
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.or(
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("plot"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.join("actors").get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.join("producer").get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%")
            );
        });
    }
```

You refer this to generate you own specification and join tables.

Comment: In your case, assume you have a `Specification<Actor> name(String name) = (root, q, b) -> b.equal(root.get(Actor_.name, name))` and you want to find movies that have this actor, how would you use this specification, rather than having to write a "copy" of this specification that has type Specification<Movie>. That's my question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how use same specification for other entity.